# Problems with running rJava on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, r, ubuntu, openstreetmap, rjava

after I recently failed to Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 the installer put back my system to the standard 14.04 configuration (That is somewhat what it said). Now I am facing problems using rJava in R together with the OpenStreetMap package.
The output of `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
is;

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/jre1.7.0_21/bin/java       3         manual mode
```

I then run: `sudo R CMD javareconf`:

```
/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: line 1: :/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: line 1: :/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre: No such file or directory
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0_75
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI progam 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: line 1: :/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: line 1: :/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre: No such file or directory
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

However, if I start working in R I get the message:

```
/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: line 1: :/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre: No such file or directory
```

OpenStreetMap throws the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cens.spatial.RTileController.getTileValues(RTileController.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Error in osmtile(x, y, zoom, type) : could not obtain tile: 39746 1 2
```

What can I do? The script I use is unchanged for since long time and worked fine before (I am not sure whether the failed upgrade is related to the error)

Comment: You should try to fix your system so that `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre` is not missing any more. Check if package `openjdk-7-jre` is installed. Do other java programs work correctly?

Comment: openjdk-7-jre is installed and at the newest version.  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre is present and i can view the files inside